# Meaning of an analogy

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Because road traffic has plummeted and the army has been put in charge of supplying towns and cities with food, illicit vehicles heading to rebel hideouts stick out like lines of powder cocaine on a mirror.

(This is a paragraph from an article title "Pandemic and War" by The Economist in the international section.)

I've checked images of lines of Coke on a mirror, but I'm sure very unsure of the analogy here. Does it mean that there are lots of illicit vehicles?

Comment: I suggest looking up the verb phrase "stick out." That may give you a sense of what the simile is doing.

Comment: "Stick out", in this context, could be replaced with "are obvious".

Comment: Yeah I just looked it up, meaning promimen of conspicuous. Just it's other meaning of protruding from a surface seemed to have resonated more, based on my flawed understanding. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thankiee. That's very helpful.

Comment: The phrasing of that paragraph isn't entirely grammatical. Is it an exact copy of the text of the article? Can you provide a link to the source?

Comment: '... stick out like red poppies in a field of yellow corn'.

Comment: Personally, I always find *The Economist* to have incredibly good grammar. Cleverer editors you will not find.

Comment: In my opinion it is a strange analogy. It's not normal to say that something "sticks out" when it is the only thing present, as would be the case with cocaine on a mirror (assuming TV portrays cocaine use accurately). The rebel vehicles described are not the only traffic present, there is still *some* other traffic (army vehicles, at minimum). Edwin's poppy analogy is much better.